# Syntax in PHP ... $row['report_id'] in MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, syntax-error

how i use `$row['report_id']`

in this MySql Query?

```
mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hours) AS summe
             FROM reports WHERE report_id = $row['report_id'];")
```

I can't find anything on google for this topic.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: remove simple quotes from $row[report_id], `mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hours) AS summe FROM reports WHERE report_id = $row[report_id];")`

Comment: @perdeu Though technically that expect `report_id` to be a constant, and falls back to the string value if the constant isn't defined. Not good practice in general. Curly braces would be another, better option `WHERE report_id =   {$row['report_id']}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hours) AS summe FROM reports WHERE report_id = " . $row['report_id']);
```

Or:

```
mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hours) AS summe FROM reports WHERE report_id = {$row['report_id']}");
```

That takes care of your specific problem. However realize you still have some serious issues:

1) You are using deprecated `mysql_*` methods and need to move to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

2) Use prepared statements then with parameter binding, right now you are wide open to SQL injection!

3) Your use of `$row['report_id']` makes it look like you are nesting queries rather than using one query with a `JOIN`. There is almost certainly an opportunity to improve whatever you're doing here.

Comment: Chances are, with the use of `$row['report_id']` in their query, that OP is also looping over the result of a previous query and nesting queries rather than using joins.... it probably makes SQL injection less of an issue here because $row['report_id'] is probably a db value (secondary injection is still a possibility), but is awful for performance and doesn't mean that the previous query isn't susceptible to a case of the little bobby tables

Comment: @MarkBaker good point, added that

Comment: Thank you for your help! :) It works and i also take your tips to heart :)